# How to disable cookies from a page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a web page created using asp.net and c# and I want cookies disabled.
I try `<SettingsCookies Enabled="false" />`. But when I open the page and Firebug the cookie is there.

How can I disable cookies?

Thank you for your help

Comment: did you means Firebug ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use following code:**

```
string MyCookieValue;

    if(Request.Cookies["ID"] != null)

        Response.Cookies["ID"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
```

Can follow this link:

http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Cookies-ASP.NET.aspx

Will get all things about cookies.

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly putting `<httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="false"/>` doesn't seem to disable 
httpOnlyCookies in ASP.NET 2.0:
 
http://nerd.steveferson.com/2007/09/14/act-sessionid-and-login-problems-with-asp-net-20/

Looks like Microsoft took the decision to not allow you to disable it from the web.config: 
http://forums.asp.net/p/976773/1240648.aspx

Possible options

```
 <httpCookies domain="" httpOnlyCookies="true|false" requireSSL="true|false" />
```